# connecting to a Unix domain socket from an AWK script

Tags: sockets, awk, unix-socket, openvpn

I want to open a Unix domain socket for both reading and writing from an AWK script. I'm using Gnu AWK.

Accoring to [this guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/TCP_002fIP-Networking.html), ordinary sockets could be opened as "/net-type/protocol/local-port/remote-host/remote-port", where "net-type" is inet4 or inet6. But could Unix domain sockets be opened this way? I found nothing in the manual.

Anyway, this is what I tried. I want to write "status 3" command in the Unix socket and read the output back.

```
    serv = "/var/etc/openvpn/serv.sock";

    printf("status 3\n") |& ("nc -U " serv)

    printf("wrote status command into serv.sock\n");
    getline ans < serv

    printf("ans = %s\n", ans);
```

But it doesn't read the data back.

```
    $ gawk -f bwlimit.awk db.txt
    wrote status command into serv.sock
    newdata =
```

Comment: not something I've done myself but you might want to try `do {
    print data |& "subprogram";
    "subprogram" |& getline results
} while (data left to process)
close("subprogram")` as described at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Two_002dway-I_002fO.html#Two_002dway-I_002fO after setting `subprogram="nc -U " serv`.

Comment: `awk` is text operator/command, and sockets are networking level operators. Better not mix. I suggest you use `netcat` command also known as `nc` to test your socket on the command line. When successful integrate `netcat` commands into `awk` script.

Comment: I agree with the two comments above.  In addition to netcat, socat is also excellent and capable of talking to UNIX domain sockets.  See http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/

Answer (score 0):

You have +/-2 syntax errors. In Awk, you almost never want to enclose strings with `(…)`. Plus, instead of `getline ans < serv`, in Gawk the correct way to read from a socket or coprocess is `socket |& getline [var]`.

Let's create an application that answers all lines received at `$serv` with "got …":

```bash
fifo="/tmp/fifo" ; mkfifo "$fifo"
cat "$fifo" | nc -l -U "$serv" | sed -u "s/^/got /" | tee -a "$fifo"
```

Now the following GNU Awk

```
BEGIN {
    serv = "/var/etc/openvpn/serv.sock"

    printf "status 3\n" |& "nc -U " serv

    printf "wrote status command into serv.sock\n"
    "nc -U " serv |& getline ans

    printf "ans = %s\n", ans
}
```

will give

```
$ gawk -f servsock.awk
wrote status command into serv.sock
ans = got status 3
```